# AbstractMethodError thrown when calling createResourceURL on RenderResponse

Tags: java, url, jsf, jboss, portlet

I'd like to call the method [createResourceURL()](http://www.bluesunrise.com/portlet-api/javax/portlet/MimeResponse.html#createResourceURL%28%29) on my [RenderResponse](http://www.bluesunrise.com/portlet-api/javax/portlet/RenderResponse.html).

Unfortunately, when I do that, I'm getting the following exception thrown:

```
Caused by:
   java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
   org.jboss.portletbridge.BufferedRenderResponseWrapper.createResourceURL()Ljavax/portlet/ResourceURL;
```

Ain't it possible in a portlet bridge environment to write a resource URL?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the version of the portlet bridge you are using only support the portlet 1.0 api while the `createResourceURL` method was introduced in version 2.0 of the portlet spec. JBoss Portal 2.7 should support the newer version, it would be strange if it bundled a bridge that only supports an older version.

Can you check whether what version you are using? The bundled version should be in `deploy/jboss-portal.sar/lib/portal-portlet-bridge-lib.jar`, but perhaps you are deploying your own version along with you application.

Comment: I've used the portlet bridge in version 1.0.0, but included the portlet-api in version 2.0. Hence the problems.

Answer (score 0):

In my JSF portlet (using the Jboss portletbridge 2.1.0) in beans I'm using with out problems:

```
    FacesContext fctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Object obj = fctx.getExternalContext().getResponse();       
    RenderResponse rresponse = (RenderResponse) obj;
    ResourceURL resourceURL = rresponse.createResourceURL();
    resourceURL.setResourceID(id);
```

Are you sure that you get the right RenderResponse object ?